# Use htaccess to rewrite subdomain files to a folder

Tags: .htaccess, file, subdomain, url-rewriting, directory

I need to rewrite a files on subdomain to files stored in the folder with name of the subdomain. Only files that start with `sitemap` should be rewritten. So, if the requests look like this:

```
http://demo.domain.com/sitemap.xml
http://demo.domain.com/sitemap_more.xml
http://test.domain.com/sitemap.xml
http://test.domain.com/sitemap_alpha.xml
```

These should rewrite to files:

```
/content/sitemaps/demo/sitemap.xml
/content/sitemaps/demo/sitemap_more.xml
/content/sitemaps/test/sitemap.xml
/content/sitemaps/test/sitemap_alpha.xml
```

So, subdomain name is used as a folder in the rewrite-to-path. This should be rewriting NOT redirecting. Also, it would be good to have rules that will work with any domain without need to change domain name everytime.

Answer (score 0):

You can match the subdomain with a condition, then rewrite it with the rule :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/content/sitemaps/%1/$1 [L]
```

Maybe you want to add a filter on .xml

Add :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.xml
```

**Edit**

For file beginning with `sitemap` :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} sitemap.*\..+$
```

This will match any string that finish with sitemap. and end. => this is a filename not an inner match of directory.

Comment: This is not taking into account that files to be rewritten must start with `sitemap`. Extension can be different than XML.

Comment: No, its not working. With RewriteRule as you suggested, server generates 500 internal error that .domain.com is not found. If I leave only path without `http://domain.com` part, nothing happens, it's not working. I think for rewrite to work, it can't include domain, rewrite should point to same domain, or subdomain in this case.

Comment: I shall see that. Let me think. But you can change domain, for sure.

Comment: Maybe, but in any case is not working. Point is to have it stay on same domain to get files, no need to go cross domain or to main domain.

Comment: Have you any log in the /var/log/apache2? You can also activate mod_rewrite logs with the RewriteLog "/var/log/apache2/rewrite.log" and RewriteLogLevel 3 (or 4).