# .htaccess subdomain to directory issue

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain, catch-all

I am currently working on a website for a client, the website I'm creating is then to be sold on to other companies to use and is done so like this:

1. Payment is recieved
2. Admin logs into 123-reg control panel and creates a new database.
3. Admin then logs into a website control panel and begins to create a new instance of the website.
4. The source filesare copied over to a new directory `/new-instance/` for example.
5. The user should be able to access it from `new-instance.website.co.uk`

Now due to some issues such as the fact after 100 sub domains they have to pay more money to 123-reg I suggested we simply set up a set of .htaccess rules to redirect the user from `new-instance.website.co.uk` to `website.co.uk/new-instance/`

Now the issues I face are that

1. I have no idea on the rewrite rule I should be using, I'm currently using this one found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664459/htaccess-point-a-subdomain-to-a-directory)
2. 123-reg seems to have catch-all sub-domains enabled, I have no access to the 123-reg panel so I don't know if they are able to turn it off, but due to this fact typing in any sub-domain that has not been set up in their control panel just shows the websites main page, therefore I have no idea if catch-all is stopping .htaccess working or if its the rules within the .htaccess file.

All relevant answers are much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below support article explains how to setup sub domains via DNS.

The stand alone subdomain product is not what you require.

How can I point a subdomain to an IP address?
http://www.123-reg.co.uk/support/answers/Domains/Domain-Configuration/how-can-i-point-a-subdomain-to-an-ip-address-2173/

All you need to do is setup the as described in the article above and then code the htaccess file accordingly.

Any problems please let me know the support ticket number.
http://www.123-reg.co.uk/support/

Ricky

Comment: I don't have direct access to the control panel so I'll have to talk them through the procedure but this looks like what I need. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I work on behalf of 123-reg.

You do NOT need to pay for sub domain DNS hosting.

You can add DNS entries via the Manage DNS section of the control panel

Regards,

Ricky

Comment: they apparently called 123-reg's support line and were informed that after 100 sub domains they would be required to pay for more.